# Kubernetes - Unable to cordon the node

Tags: kubernetes

We have on-prem cluster. I am trying to cordon a node using `kubectl cordon <node>` the command is successful, but when I am running command `kubectl get nodes` I see nodes is still ready. Where should I check next?

I didnt find any error in api-server. Where should I check? Etcd logs (how to check them) ? Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you still have some daemonsets on your node that are preventing the node from being cordoned off. As per [the guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) on Kubernetes.io, try the following:

```
kubectl drain --ignore-daemonsets <node name>
```

Once this has completed, you can safely power off the node. Once it comes back up, you can bring it back into the fold with:

```
kubectl uncordon <node name>
```

Let me know if that helps.

#kubernetes #drain #cordon

Comment: Hello @XanderS This is not about draining but cordoning, drain empty the node of any pods. Cordoning only tell scheduler to stop scheduling further workloads to cordoned node.

Comment: I realise that it is not the same, but I was offering a solution to the possible issue that may be causing the cordoning not to work as designed.